# Out of band signature application for banking transactions

Tags: digital-signature, banks, content-security-policy

I work on a banking signature project.

Signing transactions must be carried out on another application to respect the mechanism "Out Of Band". When the user makes a transaction, he must pass to a second application (out of band) in which he will find the list of tasks awaiting for signature.

Details:

The existing policy is that the user signs his transactions in the same application, i.e. on the banking application, by entering a SMS OTP.

The current objective is that the signature task should be done in another app, to strengthen security measures.

The user already has an account in the bank app, and should create a new account in the signature app, in order to sign his transactions safely.

After creating the new account, and after authentication, the user should find the list of tasks awaiting for signature, which were transferred from the bank application.

How can I match the user in both applications, so that I can transfer his unique tasks to sign

I do not know how the exchange of data between the two applications (the bank application and the signature app) will work, and how can I secure the signature app?

Comment: You'll need to provide lots more information before we can help you.

Comment: In addition to what @NeilSmithline said, banking transactions have very high security requirements in terms of protocol design, and auditing. If this is something you're planning on actually deploying, then you're going to need more help than we can give you here. However, if this is a school project or similar, then please [edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/119536/edit) your question with details of exactly what you're trying to do, what data your apps need to exchange, what your threats you are trying to protect against, any other requirements and features, etc.

Comment: it's for my Project Graduation.I do my internship in a company wich work for banks.

Comment: @Mike Ounsworth ,@Neil Smithline, i've just edited my question.thaks for answering..

Comment: Great, with the added details I think this question can now get a good answer. I've nominated it for re-opening.

Comment: @Nabylaelmohrir, Are you assume the two apps always running on the same device (phone) or it is possible that one app running on the phone and the other on a tablet?

Comment: @Abu Ubaidah the two apps can run in different devices

Comment: @Nabylaelmohrir, OK you need to come up with a common reference that the clients use to login, maybe their bank accounts. So in your DB link the account from app 1 and app 2 to the user bank account or email address.  When the user login into the bank app and issue some   transactions, your system add the sign requests of these transactions to his bank account (common reference). Then, when he login into the signature app your system check if the user has some sign requests and so on.  I hope this help you.  By the way, it is better to move your question to http://stackoverflow.com/.